# GSON Десериализация, создание подкласса

Tags: java, gson

Здравствуйте, интересует как можно создать подкласс `ListHistory` в `Person`, без сеттеров и передачи уже готового `ListHistory`.

Имеется такой JSON:

```
{
 "name":"Alexander",
 "AllHistory":[
   {
   "key":"key",
   "value":"value"
   }
 ]
}
```

Классы:

```
class Person {
   @SerializedName("name")
   String name;

   ListHistory listHistory;
}

class ListHistory{
    List<History> history = new ArrayList<>();
}

class History{
   String key;
   String value;
}
```

Deserializer:

```
@Override
public Person deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement data = json.getAsJsonObject().get("name");
    return gson.fromJson(data, Person.class);
}
```

Comment: Я бы посмотрел в сторону ручной инициализации объекта. То есть получил бы JSON, пробежался по нему и инициализировал бы класс Person.

Comment: @ezhov_da, так в этом и проблема :) Для того что-бы ручками все сделать, нужно готовое, те `ListHistory` передавать в Person, а мне не хочется что-бы что-то торчало наружу.

Comment: Передавайте в Person JSON и пусть он сам отвечает за инициализацию, либо вообще получает сам JSON и все делает, тогда вообще ничего торчать не будет. Вам нужно определиться, либо он кем то инициализируется, либо сам внутри.

Comment: @ezhov_da зачем `Person`'у знать о том как его создавать, если этим занимается `deserialize` - это как-то не правильно.

Comment: неправильно это со стороны процедурного ООП : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все как всегда проще, чем кажется.... :)

Чтоб это провернуть необходимо создать еще один `deserialize` для `ListHistory`, и регистрировать его не обязательно.

В `deserialize` для `Person`, необходимо обратиться к контексту (`JsonDeserializationContext`) и вызвать десериализацию уже для `ListHistory`

```
context.deserialize(data.getAsJsonObject().get("AllHistory").getAsJsonArray(),
new TypeToken<ListHistory>() {
    }.getType()
);
```

Ну, а далее описываем `deserialize` для `ListHistory`.

И да будет свет xD